# Relation Reflexive?

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $N_4=\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $R\circ R=R$. How would I prove that $R$ is reflexive?

I am geting this statement as false, Please Let me know , How to prove this ?

Comment: @pratik, Brian M. Scott's answer is the same as the one in the comment of Brent Kerby to his answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190191/18398).  Why do you feel the need to ask the question again when it already had an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $R=\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$.

- Show that $R\circ R=R$.
- Is $R$ reflexive as a relation on $N_4$?

Comment: Is this statemant is True or false ?

Comment: R is a Relation on $N_4$

Comment: @pratik: Yes, $R$ is a relation on $N_4$, but is it a *reflexive* relation on $N_4$? If you understand the definition of reflexivity, you should be able to answer that easily. If not, we need to get that cleared up.

Comment: what if we assume that R is reflexive as a relation on $N_4$ . Can it be done now ?

Comment: @pratik: Can what be done? If you assume that a relation $R$ is reflexive, then of course it will be reflexive, whether $R\circ R=R$ or not, but that seems rather pointless. If you simply do the two things suggested in my answer, you’ll be able to answer your original question. If you can’t do those things, then you need to back up and get a better understanding of composition or reflexivity, so that you have the necessary fundamentals in place to answer the question.

Comment: If we take R = {1,1} then Above statement would be false. ? I think so

Comment: @pratik: You mean the original statement in your question? Yes, it’s false. For this $R$ we do have $R\circ R=R$, and $R$ is not reflexive on $N_4$, because it doesn’t contain $\langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle$, or $\langle 4,4\rangle$.